# search combination of words in worksheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, performance

I need to find the row which as combination of words (Keyword - Column 1 , keyword 2 - column 2 ,  keyword 3 - column 3) of sheet1  with sheet 2 which as more than 800 rows and 275 columns.

I have done a coding but it gives a result as "not responding". Please help me to sort out this issue.

below is the coding:-

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim keyword As String
Dim keyword1 As String
Dim keyword2 As String
Dim keyword3 As String
Dim k As Long
Dim k1 As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set XML = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XML")
Set rn = XML.UsedRange

k = rn.Rows.Count + rn.Row - 1
Debug.Print (k)
For i = 1 To k

k1 = rn.Columns.Count + rn.Column - 1
Debug.Print (k1)
For j = 1 To k1

cellAYvalue = XML.Cells(i, j)

For a = 2 To 261

MatchAttempt = 0

keyword_Flag = False
keyword1_Flag = False
keyword2_Flag = False
keyword3_Flag = False
keyword4_Flag = False
keyword5_Flag = False

keyword = Trim(UCase(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Keyword").Cells(a, 2)))
keyword1 = Trim(UCase(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Keyword").Cells(a, 3)))
keyword2 = Trim(UCase(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Keyword").Cells(a, 4)))
keyword3 = Trim(UCase(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Keyword").Cells(a, 5)))
keyword4 = Trim(UCase(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Keyword").Cells(a, 6)))
keyword5 = Trim(UCase(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Keyword").Cells(a, 7)))

If keyword <> "" Then
    keyword_Flag = True: MatchAttempt = MatchAttempt + 1
End If
If keyword1 <> "" Then
    keyword1_Flag = True: MatchAttempt = MatchAttempt + 1
End If
If keyword2 <> "" Then
    keyword2_Flag = True: MatchAttempt = MatchAttempt + 1
End If
If keyword3 <> "" Then
    keyword3_Flag = True: MatchAttempt = MatchAttempt + 1
End If
If keyword4 <> "" Then
    keyword4_Flag = True: MatchAttempt = MatchAttempt + 1
End If
If keyword5 <> "" Then
    keyword5_Flag = True: MatchAttempt = MatchAttempt + 1
End If


        MatchedCount = 0

        Description = Trim(UCase(cellAYvalue = XML.Cells(i, j)))
        Description1 = Trim(UCase(cellAYvalue = XML.Cells(i, j)))
        Description2 = Trim(UCase(cellAYvalue = XML.Cells(i, j)))
        Description3 = Trim(UCase(cellAYvalue = XML.Cells(i, j)))
        Description4 = Trim(UCase(cellAYvalue = XML.Cells(i, j)))
        Description5 = Trim(UCase(cellAYvalue = XML.Cells(i, j)))
        EXITloop = Trim(UCase(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Keyword").Cells(a, 1)))

        If EXITloop = "" Then
        Exit For
        End If


              MatchComplete = False

              If keyword_Flag = True Then
                If keyword = Description Then
                    MatchedCount = MatchedCount + 1
                    If MatchAttempt = MatchedCount Then MatchComplete = True
                End If
              End If
                If keyword_Flag1 = True Then
                If keyword1 = Description1 Then
                    MatchedCount = MatchedCount + 1
                    If MatchAttempt = MatchedCount Then MatchComplete = True
                End If
              End If
              If keyword_Flag2 = True Then
                If keyword2 = Description2 Then
                    MatchedCount = MatchedCount + 1
                    If MatchAttempt = MatchedCount Then MatchComplete = True
                End If
              End If
              If keyword_Flag3 = True Then
                If keyword3 = Description3 Then
                    MatchedCount = MatchedCount + 1
                    If MatchAttempt = MatchedCount Then MatchComplete = True
                End If
              End If
              If keyword_Flag4 = True Then
                If keyword4 = Description4 Then
                    MatchedCount = MatchedCount + 1
                    If MatchAttempt = MatchedCount Then MatchComplete = True
                End If
              End If
              If keyword_Flag5 = True Then
                If keyword5 = Description5 Then
                    MatchedCount = MatchedCount + 1
                    If MatchAttempt = MatchedCount Then MatchComplete = True
                End If
              End If


                inin = Trim(UCase(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XML").Cells(i, 112)))
                ouou = Trim(UCase(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Keyword").Cells(a, 8)))


            If MatchComplete = True Then

                    ouou = inin

            End If


a = a + 0

Next

j = j + 0

Next

i = i + 0

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub
```

---

**Edit: More details**

---

I have a workbook with two worksheets

Sheet 1 is having “N” number of data with 807 rows and 277 column

Sheet 2 is having the standard keyword combination (201 combinations) set.

Note: - each combination from sheet 2 can be available in any of the row or columns of sheet 1, But combination match should be in row wise alone.

Requirements: - Need to find the keyword combination from sheet 2 in sheet 1 once the combination found in sheet 1 we need to fetch the output.

**Sheet 1 (Data Sheet)**

[image: Sheet1]

**Sheet 2 (Keyword Sheet)**

[image: Sheet2]

**Searching keywords from sheet 2 in sheet 1**

[image: Search]

**keywords can find in many cells of sheet 1 (Yellow highlighted) but the combination will be find in only one row and we need to find that row (Green highlighted)**

[image: K]

once we have found the row in sheet 1 which has the combination we need to fetch the fourth value from the last combination word and paste it in the 10th column of sheet 2.

E.g

in sheet 1

we have found the combination 100th row

in that row keyword 1 in (100,20)
keyword 2 in (100,40)
keyword 3 in (100,60)

then output should be need to copy the value from cell (100,64) in sheet 1 then need to paste in 10th column of sheet 2 to respective combination row of sheet 2.

Comment: You are doing all of this logic inside of three nested for loops. How big is `k` and `k1`? Are those in the hundreds?

Comment: yeah K is 807 and K1 is 277

Comment: Oh... here.  AT the end of each for loop you increment your a, j, and i values... but you don't `a = a + 0` is just `a`. You just iterate forever and ever

Comment: And if k is 807 and k1 is 277 then `807*277*259 = 57,896,601` loops. I see there is an exit in there, but (not totally following your logic) that is going to spin for a LONG time.

Comment: So any solution for this , I have tried many but am not getting any points to optimize

Comment: The question is a bit complex and you provided quite a few details, but we still need more. It can be solved by combining AutoFilters for each `Key word` but we need to map all `Key words` in `Sheet2` to columns in `Sheet1`. For example: _look for **`Key word 1`** in column `CB` (**`col 80`**) on `Sheet1`_, then _look for **`Key word 2`** in column `CC` (**`col 81`**) on `Sheet1`_. Please provide all 6 columns in `Sheet1` (exactly) to be mapped to the 6 `Key words` on `Sheet2`

Comment: And if I understand correctly, once we identify the row in `Sheet1`, copy the value in `Sheet1.col64` to `Sheet2.col10` for the matching rows

Answer (score 0):

This identifies `Sheet2` rows in `Sheet1`, based on the first 3 columns as keywords

Once a record is found, it copies value from the 3rd col in `Sheet1` in the 10th column of `Sheet2`

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Const FR = 2    'Start row
    Const KC = 3    'Last Keyword column
    Const TC = 10   'Target column

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet:   Set ws1 = Sheet1    'Or: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet:   Set ws2 = Sheet2

    Dim lr1 As Long:        lr1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim lr2 As Long:        lr2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim arr1 As Variant:    arr1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(FR, 1), ws1.Cells(lr1, KC))
    Dim arr2 As Variant:    arr2 = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(FR, 1), ws2.Cells(lr2, KC))

    Dim d1 As Object:       Set d1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim d2 As Object:       Set d2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim dr As Object:       Set dr = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")   'Result

    LoadDictionary d1, arr1
    LoadDictionary d2, arr2
    GetKeywords d2, d1, dr

    Dim r As Long

    arr2 = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(FR, 1), ws2.Cells(lr2, TC))
    If dr.Count > 0 Then
        For r = 1 To lr2
            If dr.Exists(r) Then arr2(r, TC) = arr2(r, KC)  'Or arr2(r, TC) = dr(r)
        Next
    End If
    ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(FR, 1), ws2.Cells(lr2, TC)) = arr2
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub LoadDictionary(ByRef d As Object, arr As Variant)   'Expects 2-d array

    Dim r As Long, c As Long, k As String

    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        k = "|"
        For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            k = k & arr(r, c) & "|"     'Concatenate all columns
        Next
        d(k) = r
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub GetKeywords(ByRef d1 As Object, ByRef d2 As Object, ByRef dr As Object)

    Dim r As Long, k As String, arr As Variant

    For r = 0 To d1.Count - 1
        k = d1.Keys()(r)
        If d2.Exists(k) Then
            arr = Split(k, "|")
            dr(d1(k)) = arr(UBound(arr) - 1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

.

Test **`Sheet 1`**

[image: TestSheet1]

Test **`Sheet 2`**

[image: TestSheet2]

---

`Sheet1 Rows: 1,001, Cols: 501; Sheet2 Rows: 1,001, Cols: 501 - Time: 0.023 sec`

New info:

> Row 1 - Keyword 1 , keyword 2 , keyword 3 (once we find the row with
>   this order then we need to fetch the 4th value from keyword 3 in the
>   same row) and paste in 10 column of sheet 2

Comment: hi sir, Remarkable increase in speed but version 2 is my need

Comment: and once the keyword's in the sheet 2 if found in any row of sheet 1 then need to fetch the fourth value from the last keyword of that respective row

Comment: Row 1 - Keyword 1 , keyword 2 , keyword 3 (once we find the row with this order then we need to fetch the 4th value from keyword 3 in the same row) and paste in 10 column of sheet 2

Comment: I made changes based on the new info. Let me know if there are any issues

Comment: I will add a new question since am unable to add images

Comment: please search this question description sir "To find the combination of keywords using VBA excel"

Comment: your help will be highly helpful to me if this crux has been breaked.

Comment: @SRI - Your [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379258/to-find-the-combination-of-keywords-using-vba-excel) will probably be closed. The normal process is to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50297102/edit) your question if you need to provide more details (I embedded your new details and the external images within this question)